# How not to print captured log on success in python-behave

Tags: python, logging, python-behave

I am trying to capture the logs of my python-behave tests (produced by the `logging` module) by using this command to run them:

```sh
behave -f pretty --logging-level INFO --capture "features/file_system_operations.feature"
```

This executes the tests, but even though they are passing, all my info lines are printed to sceen instead of being captured, eg.:
[image: behave prints INFO lines when --capture is set]

When I change the logging level to warning, the code properly responds and no lines are printed:

```sh
behave -f pretty --logging-level WARNING --capture "features/file_system_operations.feature"
```

Results a clean printout:
[image: clean python-behave printout]

How can I ask behave to have `INFO` `logging` lines printed only if a test fails?

Comment: This looks to be connected with docker run. I don't see the same behaviour while running without docker.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to find was going on, and it seems like `logging` imported multiple times is the root cause. I am not sure if this is a feature or a bug, but will try to patch around the issue by extracting logging functionality into its own module.